# Use just Controller name as route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to access my `NewsList` route by that URL: `http://domain.com/news`

I have three routes like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NewsList",
    url: "News",
    defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "List" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NewsDetail",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{title}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Details", title = "", id = 0 }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I can use the `Default` and `NewsDetail` routes with no problems, but `NewsList` route cannot be accessed with the URL I provided below with the current configuration. When I try to access the `NewsList` route, I need to use the URL: `http://domain.com/news/list`.

EDIT: If I use `http://domain.com/news`, I get a `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden` error on the screen.

Is it possible to ignore the action in this case?

Comment: What happens when you go to `/news`? What you have looks fine.

Comment: What happens? I see a "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden"

Comment: Ok. That doesn't mean your route isn't working. There could be any number of reasons you're being forbidden. There's not enough here to help you with that though.

Comment: What else do you need? My controller and action names are as they are written in the controller. You say that it should have worked and my NewsList route is valid?

Comment: Yep. If the route were not valid, you would either get a 404 or some other action. The fact that it's forbidden means it's hitting *something*, there's just some other issue.

Comment: I see... Do you have any idea what could couse a route problem like this? I practically didn't change anything on the sample project except adding some views. I totally have three controllers including Home. And the other one is using the default route.

Comment: My best guess is make sure there's not a "news" directory in your project. If there is, that will take precedence and you'll get a 403 for attempting a directory listing.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I had a hidden folder inside my project. I had it there to store some files and then forgot about it, it's even not included in the project. Put that in an answer and I will mark it as answer to close this question, since it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there's not a "news" directory in your project. If there is, that will take precedence and you'll get a 403 for attempting a directory listing.